# Node cron permission Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, open filename

Tags: node.js, cron, file-permissions

I have this script that I want to run every minute inside a test.js file:

```
#!/Users/nick/.nvm/versions/node/v18.3.0/bin/node
// ^ shebang line

require('dotenv').config({ path: '../../.env' });
const { Client } = require('pg'); // do NOT convert to import, otherwise it will fail

const dbConfig = {
    host: process.env.PG_HOST,
    port: Number(process.env.PG_PORT),
    user: process.env.PG_USER,
    password: process.env.PG_PASSWORD,
    database: process.env.PG_DB,
};

async function runProcedure() {
    const client = new Client(dbConfig);

    try {
        await client.connect();

        // Call your stored procedure
        const result = await client.query('CALL ManageBalanceDueAndCommissionStatus()');

        console.log('Stored procedure executed successfully:', result);
    } catch (error) {
        console.error('Error executing stored procedure:', error);
    } finally {
        await client.end();
    }
}

runProcedure();
```

And I am doing this (in the CLI on my Mac) to try to get the cron working:

Run: `crontab -e`

Add the following inside:
`* * * * * node ~/Users/nick/Documents/cron/test.js > ~/Users/nick/Documents/cron/logs/cron.log 2>&1`

And I got this error when I tried that:

`/bin/sh: node: command not found`

So then I tried changing the cron to this:

`* * * * * ~/.nvm/versions/node/v18.3.0/bin/node ~/Users/nick/Documents/cron/test.js > ~/Users/nick/Documents/cron/logs/cron.log 2>&1`

However, I get this error:

```
node:internal/fs/utils:345
    throw err;
    ^

Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, open '/Users/nick/Documents/cron/test.js'
    at Object.openSync (node:fs:591:3)
    at Object.readFileSync (node:fs:459:35)
    at Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1122:18)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:981:32)
    at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:827:12)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (node:internal/modules/run_main:77:12)
    at node:internal/main/run_main_module:17:47 {
  errno: -1,
  syscall: 'open',
  code: 'EPERM',
  path: '/Users/nick/Documents/cron/test.js'
}

Node.js v18.3.0
```

I have also tried changing the permissions of the test.js file - when running `ls -l` it shows the permission as `-rwxr-xr-x`.

I have looked at other posts, researched elsewhere, etc, and I am out of ideas. Does anyone know how can this be fixed? Or is not, what alternative approaches (many) do I have to running a cron javascript file? (it just calls a stored procedure in a Postgres database)